# How to check how many tests are in a project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to retrieve information how many tests methods are in project I was working in, since company asked me to do it for their statistics.

This is an old project I worked in written in Java. It's quite big project. Is there a quick way, perhaps shortcut in IntelliJ, to find out this information without running a tests?

Edited: specified I'm looking for test methods.

Comment: Do you mean test files or test methods?

Comment: @zoko0 Did you find my answer useful? If so, I'll appreciate if you thumb it up and mark it as the selected answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer, I don't remember what I meant exactly, but I recall it wasn't that easy, since we also had a lot of parametrized tests in project. Thanks for support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ctrl` + `Shift` + `f` to get the `Find` window.

Now enter `@Test` and click the `Open in Find Window`.

There you will see something like that:

> Found Occurrences 397 Occurrences